# pd.io.sql.read_sqlで2つのコードの出力結果を同じにしたい

Tags: python, python3, pandas, postgresql

下記の二つのコードで同様の結果を出力したいのですが
1のコードは[0 rows x 112 columns]と上手くいかないのですが
2のコードで実行した時、[1 rows x 112 columns]と
取りたいデータがとれます。
1のコードのどこを修正すれば2のコードと同じ出力になるかご指摘頂けたらと思います。

1.

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
import pandas as pd

url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:*****@127.0.0.1:****/test'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)

table_name ='test2'
name = '123456789101234'
query = "select * from {} WHERE 'test_code' = '{}'".format(table_name, name)
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(query, engine)
print('#############')
print(df)
```

---

2.

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
import pandas as pd

url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:*****@127.0.0.1:****/test'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)
table_name ='test2' 
name = '123456789101234' 
query = 'select * from {}'.format(table_name) 
df2 = pd.io.sql.read_sql(query, engine) 
print('#############') 
df2 = df2[df2['test_code'] == name]
print(df2)
```

Comment: 編集時にソースコードの部分だけ選択した状態で `{}` を押すと見やすく整形されますので、次回から試して下さい。また、区切り線を入れたい場合には `----` (`-`を4つ)を使ってみて下さい。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。次回から実践してみます。

Comment: `print(df2[df2['test_code'] == name])`だとどうなりますか？

Comment: すみません。質問にミスがありましたので修正致します。df2[df2['test_code'] == name]だと[1 rows x 112 columns]と上手くいきます。

Comment: すみません。修正したいコードは1の方になります。只今質問修正させて頂きました。

Comment: なるほど、わかりました。では、`"select * from {} WHERE test_code = '{}'".format(table_name, name)`に変えてみるとどうなりますか？ （`test_code`を囲んでいる`' '`を外してみてください）

Comment: 実行したところエラーになってしまいます。

Comment: すみません。シングルクォートで実行してのエラーでした。"select * from {} WHERE test_code = '{}'".format(table_name, name)でうまく[1 rows x 112 columns]で表示させれました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決したようで良かったです:)　回答を承認して頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test_code`を囲んでいるシングルクオート`' '`を外してみてください。
シングルクオート付きのテーブル名だと解釈されていると思います。

```
query = "select * from {} WHERE test_code = '{}'".format(table_name, name)
```